# How can I get this table in HTML?

Tags: html

Now, I need a table like this in HTML. 
I cannot assign the column with width. How can I get this table using HTML code

[image]

Comment: Can you please put your out here ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP does not show any attempts to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have cells of arbitrarily different widths, this is generally a standard behavior of tables from any space, e.g. Excel, otherwise it's no longer a table but just a list of text.

You can however have cells span multiple columns, you can declare a col value of 5% and use colspan to create your custom width "cells".

It's definitely not elegant or practical but I can't think of any other way of doing this on a single table.

```html
<table width="100%" border="1" bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <col width="5%">
      <tr>
        <td colspan=20>Title 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=1>A</td>
        <td colspan=9>3</td>
        <td colspan=10>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=1>B</td>
        <td colspan=9>6</td>
        <td colspan=10>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=1>C</td>
        <td colspan=9>9</td>
        <td colspan=10>10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=20>Title 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=4>11</td>
        <td colspan=4>11</td>
        <td colspan=4>11</td>
        <td colspan=4>12</td>
        <td colspan=4>2</td>
      </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: For your interest, you don't need 20 columns. You can [do it in 7](http://jsfiddle.net/kewh0y7a/)